# How to remove sale price on specific product in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

### UPD. I don't need to recalculate order or cart, I need to remove sale price for product if after successful order it's stock quantity comes to zero.

I need to remove sale price from product if it's out of stock. I've found some code snippets but none of them worked. Can't find right solution. Here's my function below, please advise:

```
function remove_sale_price ( $order_id ) { 
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $prod_id  = $item->get_product_id();
        $name     = $item->get_name();
        $product  = wc_get_product($prod_id);
        if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
            $prod_id  = $item->get_variation_id();
            $product  = wc_get_product($prod_id);
        }
        $quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        $note     = 'Sale price removed on <b>' . $name . '</b>';
        if ( ($quantity < 1) && (!empty($product->get_sale_price()) ) ) {
            
            /*** HERE I NEED TO REMOVE SALE PRICE FROM PRODUCT ***/

            $order->add_order_note( $note );
       }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'remove_sale_price');
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'remove_sale_price');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
$product->set_sale_price('');
$product->save();
```

I didn't know I need to save product. Here's my whole function:

```
function remove_sale_price ( $order_id ) { 
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $prod_id  = $item->get_product_id();
        $name     = $item->get_name();
        $product  = wc_get_product($prod_id);
        if ($product->is_type( 'variable' )) {
            $prod_idv  = $item->get_variation_id();
            $product   = wc_get_product($prod_idv);
        }
        $quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
        $note     = 'Removed sale price on <b>«' . $name . '»</b>.';
        if ( $quantity < 1 ) {
            $order->add_order_note( $note );
            $product->set_sale_price('');
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'remove_sale_price' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'remove_sale_price' );
```

Function explanation: if order status is "Processing" or "Completed" (which means stock reduced) function will check stock quantity for products in order (in my case I need to check only simple and variable products). If stock is less then 1 (0, -1, etc) it removes sale price from product or variation. Tested on Woocommerce 4.3.1. This function doesn't affect order.